# users getting created in joomla

Tags: php, web, joomla

attached image has the user list which were created without my knowledge in a website build on joomla framework. Can someone help me understand how these users are getting created and how to stop them created?[image]

Comment: I'd guess they've filled out your Joomla install's registration form.

Comment: I changed "Allow User Registration" under user: options to NO.hope that helps fixing the issue. Will monitor and confirm in a day. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using? 3.5.1?

Answer (score 0):

I changed "Allow User Registration" under user: options to NO and that fixed..

I was able to create users from the registration page and could see new users in the list. I was able to create users which i was thinking error. infact its working the way its destined to..

Link that i followed https://docs.joomla.org/Help35:Components_Users_Configuration

thanks ceejayoz for your comment.